# Addition of two random number , with four options on swipe viewcontroller is not work perfectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe-gesture

I am developing application of addition of two random  number with their four options , On Swipe of View-controller the two numbers and their options will change, for change options I use array to marge that number & print it again. But on swipe of view it will not work perfectly, smooth swipe is not happen, here is my code please help me.

```
-(void)makeAddition
{
   number1 = (arc4random()%100)+1; //Generates Number from 1 to 100.
   number2 = (arc4random()%100)+1;
   addition = number1+number2;
   wrongOne = (arc4random()%100)+1;
   wrongTwo = (arc4random()%100)+1;
   wrongThree = (arc4random()%100)+1;
   NSString *w1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",wrongOne];
   NSString *w2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",wrongTwo];
   NSString *w3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",wrongThree];
   answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",addition];
     // add randam values in array
    [_AnswerArray addObject:answer];
    [_AnswerArray addObject:w1];
    [_AnswerArray addObject:w2];
    [_AnswerArray addObject:w3];

    NSLog(@"%@ add objects in array",_AnswerArray);
     // mearge arrays object here
    NSUInteger count = [_AnswerArray count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        NSUInteger nElements = count - i;
        NSUInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [_AnswerArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];

        NSLog(@"%@ exchange array objects",_AnswerArray);
    }  // if addition is less than 100 then print number & options
    if (addition <= 100)
    {

        _numberOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number1];
        _numberTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number2];

          // checking all four buttons value  with array value
        if (_AnswerOne.currentTitle != _AnswerTwo.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerOne.currentTitle != _AnswerThree.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerOne.currentTitle != _AnswerFour.currentTitle) {
             [_AnswerOne setTitle:[_AnswerArray objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        if (_AnswerTwo.currentTitle != _AnswerOne.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerTwo.currentTitle != _AnswerThree.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerTwo.currentTitle != _AnswerFour.currentTitle) {
            [_AnswerTwo setTitle:[_AnswerArray objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        if (_AnswerThree.currentTitle != _AnswerOne.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerThree.currentTitle != _AnswerTwo.currentTitle ||     
            _AnswerThree.currentTitle != _AnswerFour.currentTitle) {
            [_AnswerThree setTitle:[_AnswerArray objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        if (_AnswerFour.currentTitle != _AnswerOne.currentTitle || 
            _AnswerFour.currentTitle != _AnswerTwo.currentTitle ||     
            _AnswerFour.currentTitle != _AnswerThree.currentTitle) {
             [_AnswerFour setTitle:[_AnswerArray objectAtIndex:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    [_AnswerArray removeAllObjects];
 }

-(void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer  *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self makeAddition];
}
```

Comment: Please add variable declarations: I don't see what `_AnswerX`, and `_AnswerArray` do. To compare string in ObjectiveC don't use `!=` but `[str1 compare: str2]`

Comment: @Szu  _AnswerX is buttons which take _AnswerArray values with Objectindex,

Comment: i am not getting [str1 compare : str2] , here i check not equal too @Szu